# Refrain from having to repeat html layout

Tags: php, html, forms, frame

I am creating a site which will have an html frame and multiple forms using this same html frame. the forms use php codes.
How can I make it so that the forms don't all have to include the html frame over and over again?

Comment: As you are using PHP I would suggest using a template engine like http://twig.sensiolabs.org/ I use it and love it.

Comment: You write `<?php include('iframe.php'); ?>`in your page and in `ìframe.php` there is the html code for your iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are including the html with [`include`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php) or [`require`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require.php) you must use [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include-once.php) or [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php). Otherwise you need a contition to **check if the html is already loaded**.

Answer (score 0):

Create a php page and create the frame there and just include it in all the other pages. Given that the other pages are php pages.